# I am getting an Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child in my index.js page. Is there a workaround

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Index.js code here

```
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

I am guessing the error is not comming from the code above and neither is it comming  the App.js code.
App.js code here

```
        function App() {
          return (
            <div className="App">
              <header className="App-header">
                <AppNavbar/>
                <ShoppingList/>
              </header>
            </div>
          );
       }
```

Here's an excerpt from ShoppingList.js. Hope this is of help:
I think this is where the problem originates because I changed `items.map` `this.state.items.map` and the error was, `items.map is not defined`.

```
    class ShoppingList extends Component {
        state = {
            items: [
                { id: uuid(), name: 'Eggs'},
                { id: uuid(), name: 'Milk'},
                { id: uuid(), name: 'Apples'},
                { id: uuid(), name: 'Water'},
            ]
        }

    render() {
        const items= this.state;
        return(
            <container>
                <Button
                color="dark"
                style={{marginBottom : '2rem'}}
                onClick={() => {
                    const name = prompt("Enter item");
                    if (name) {
                        this.setState( state => ({
                            items: [...state.items, {id: uuid(), name}]
                        }));

                    }
                }}

                >Add Item</Button>

                <ListGroup>
                    <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
                    {this.state.items.map(({ id, name}) => (
                        <CSSTransition key="{id}" timeout="500" classNames="fade">

                        </CSSTransition>
                    ))}
                    </TransitionGroup>
                </ListGroup>

               </container>
        )
      }

    }
```

I have checked many other errors similar to this but without any success. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Looks like your `<App />` is returning some array.... wrap it with with `React.Fragment` ... also share the code of your App.js

Comment: Show us the `jsx` of App.js file

Comment: shared the JSX of App.js

Comment: @gdh I tried wrapping `<App/>` with `React.Fragment` but the error message still exists.

Comment: What is <container > component ? JSX component must start with a capital letter.

Comment: Fixed that, `container` is changed to `Container`. Error message remains though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly, as per [react-transition-group documentation](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group#TransitionGroup-prop-children), you will need to put the stuff you need transition inside `<CSSTransition>`. So in your case, put your `ListGroup.Item` and `Button` inside `CSSTransition`.
- Also, you have used wrong `key`(string) in `<CSSTransition key="{id}"`. So use provide unique key - like this - `<CSSTransition key={id}`

Working copy of your code is here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-snow-gwilb?file=/src/ShoppingList.js

Comment: Move the `Button` to the outside of `ListGroup` and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
<AppNavbar/>
<ShoppingList/>
```

under 
`<div></div>` tag as header might need single element under it.

Comment: Yes mate, tried that as well. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then try commenting all components and gradually introduce single component or just div. This doesnt seem big technical issue.